# Cannot initialize/error correct object name with shorthand if/else

Tags: python, python-3.x

Couldn't think of a better way to ask this question, but I'm initializing an object, and for the name I'm trying to error correct with shorthand if else in case anything but a string isn't entered. If it isn't a string, then they have to re-enter it. Trying to make my code shorter and learning how to make error-free code.

Here's my code:

```
def __init__(self, name, price, quantity):
    self.name = name if isinstance(name, str) else self.name = input()
```

It keeps saying that `name` and `isinstance` aren't used. Is there a better way to go about error correcting for initializing an object?

Comment: `self.name = name if isinstance(name, str) else input()` but what do you mean by "they didn't enter a string?". If they enter something, it _has_ to be a string.

Comment: That did it, I assume I just don't understand shorthand well enough. Do I not have to reiterate the variable that's being assigned? Now I feel dumb. Thanks for the response!

Comment: it's ternary. are you sure something else than a string can be entered?

Comment: That is not "shorthand if/else" As you are discovering, if - else statements are **statements**, whereas what you are trying to do is use a *conditional expression* are **expressions**. You cannot have statements inside your conditional expression, like assignment statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you can't do an assignment in a conditional expression (an `sth1 if ... else sth2`):

```
 def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name if isinstance(name, str) else self.name = input()
```

throws:

```
  File "<ipython-input-23-a0246a5f014d>", line 3
    self.name = name if isinstance(name, str) else self.name = input()
               ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression
```

However, you can just omit the `self.name =` after the `else` (which is the reason for the `SyntaxError`):

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name if isinstance(name, str) else input()
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
def __init__(self, name):
    if isinstance(name, str):
        self.name = name 
    else:
        self.name = input()
```